# Django model puzzle && default values that are dynamic

Tags: django, django-models

I have looked at many questions, but haven't found any quite what I am looking for. I apologize if I missed similar questions.

Here is my basic outline of what I am trying to build (and having trouble with). I am building a meal plan where meals are made up of dishes...dishes are made up of Ingredients (a food item plus the quantity), and then the actual food items such as almonds, water, spinach, etc.

An example of this is the meal of Breakfast...it is made up of two dishes of (1) Cereal and (2) Coffee...the dish of cereal is made up of the ingredients (1) Milk with 200g and (2) cereal with 200g.

I have a Food Model, Dish Model, Ingredient Model && Meal Model that allows me to build that.

Here are my models to get idea (abbreviated):

```
class Food(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Dish(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    instructions = models.TextField()
    food = models.ManyToManyField(Food, through='Ingredient')

class Ingredient(models.Model):
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    dish = models.ForeignKey(Dish, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class Meal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=1)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    dishes = models.ManyToManyField(Dish)
    time = models.DateTimeField(default=now, blank=True)
```

With these, and appropriate admin.py setup, I am able to create a food item...and then I can create a dish where I select a food item and type a quantity...and then I can add these dishes to a meal.

**HOWEVER**, (sorry for long post)...here is my issue:
I would like to create meals that have a specific quantities of food in each dish based off of the template dish...for example a Strawberry Smoothie could have 200g strawberry and 200g milk.

Now when someone builds a meal, they can select 'Strawberry Smoothie' as a dish, but I need them to have the ability to then update the quantities for their specific meal only. So if they only had 100g of Strawberry, then they should be able to edit that for their meal only. The next time they make a meal and select 'Strawberry Smoothie', it will again default to 200g.

I cannot figure out how to set up my models and admin to allow for this, as someone will need to select a dish when building a meal and then dynamically have those ingredients show up with their default values, and be editable and saved to their own instance.

I hope that makes sense...thanks for any advice!

### EDIT

(clarification)
I hope this is clearer with the following description:

I am creating a *template* (of dishes) that I would like to be dynamically shown in the admin form (for creating a meal).

A dish is a template (recommended recipe basically) consisting of the ingredients and their amounts. For example, a template dish of Strawberry Smoothie would be 200g milk && 200g strawberry.

When someone creates a meal, they will be able to select and add as many dish templates as they would like to their meal. However, as these dish templates are just templates...I need them to be able to edit the amounts and ingredients for their specific meal only.

For example, I create a meal and I call it Breakfast. In this meal, I select the dish template of (1) Scrambled Eggs && (2) Strawberry Smoothie. When someone selects these dishes, I would like for the dishes and their ingredients to show up and be editable. So when I select the Strawberry Smoothie, I would get the list of ingredients for it of 200g milk && 200g strawberry...but in my specific meal, I would like to add 100g of blueberries and use 250g of milk. In this way, I can basically import a template of the dish, but then edit it as I see fit for my meal.

Comment: Where do things like 'Strawberry smootie' exists now?

Comment: That is considered a dish, and is in a table called meals_dish

Comment: There is a bit of overlp between your dish and meal isn't there?

Comment: what is the difference between meal and dish class?? arent they both same as you mentioned?

Comment: I am open to new setups, this was just my original thoughts...sorry for any confusion. A meal is MADE UP of dishes, just like a dish is MADE UP of ingredients. Does that make any sense?

Comment: Well this a bit confusing. How about posting your raw database mmodels on codereview and asking them for their opinion?

Comment: @e4c5 That's all great if he has already implemented the feature. For now, there's not much Code Review can do.

Comment: On the contrary @mast he is asking for a review of his table design.

Comment: @e4c5 Of-course, he can ask for a review. But this part: "I cannot figure out how to set up my models and admin to allow for this" has no place there.

Comment: Hello everyone...sorry for any confusion, this is harder to explain than I thought. I have edited my question and I believe it makes more sense with my bottom edit. I really appreciate any advice/suggestions!